# jquery show and toggle functions not working

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

To quickly preface this I'm doing a web design introduction course and we need to have a basic filter feature on our site that we were told to use the filter by class method for.

For my site I'm filtering music album covers by genre but I want them to each be able to be in the same genre. The code I have written so far hides all the album cover elements ok but won't then show only the ones I want.

I have some comments in for debugging and I have also tried in one of the lines to be more specific about what divs to show i.e. ones with more than one class.

```
$("ul.rock").click(function() {
        console.log("rock clicked");
        $("div.recordElement").toggle();
        $("div.recordElement.pop").toggle();
        $(".dropDownMenu").toggle();
    });
```

The div with the class dropDownMenu also needs to be hidden as it's a dropdown menu from which the user selects a genre which needs to be hidden after the user makes a selection.

```
<div id="dropDownMenu" class="dropDownMenu">
                    <ul class="rock">Rock</ul>
                    <ul class="pop">Pop</ul>
                    <ul class="metal">Metal</ul>
                    <ul class="alternative">Alternative</ul>
                    <ul class="country">Country</ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="inStoreRecordsContainer">
                <div class="recordElement" class="pop">
                    <img src="img/inStoreMusic/bowie.jpg">
                    <p class="recordInfo">David Bowie<br>Aladdin Sane</p>
                </div>
                <div class="recordElement" class="rock" class="metal">
                    <img src="img/inStoreMusic/metallica.jpg">
                    <p class="recordInfo">Metallica<br>Master of Puppets</p>
                </div>
                <div class="recordElement" class="rock" class="pop">
                    <img src="img/inStoreMusic/nirvana.jpg">
                    <p class="recordInfo">Nirvana<br>Nevermind</p>
                </div>
                <div class="recordElement" class="pop">
                    <img src="img/inStoreMusic/blink182.jpg">
                    <p class="recordInfo">Blink 182<br>California</p>
                </div>
                <div class="recordElement" class="pop">
                    <img src="img/inStoreMusic/beatles.jpg">
                    <p class="recordInfo">The Beatles<br>Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band</p>
                </div>
                <div class="recordElement" class="pop">
                    <img src="img/inStoreMusic/beyonce.jpg">
                    <p class="recordInfo">Beyoncé<br>Beyoncé <i>(not a typo)</i></p>
                </div>
                <div class="recordElement" class="country">
                    <img src="img/inStoreMusic/cash.jpg">
                    <p class="recordInfo">Jonny Cash<br>CASH</p>
                </div>
```

Could it be that I'm trying to do this with elements with more than one class? I tried googling for a solution and other users solved the same problem by replacing show/hide with toggle, whereas neither are working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you have multiple `class` attributes.  You need to add all your classes to the same attribute tab like this: `class="recordElement rock metal"`.

The html parser generally uses the last attribute of a give name, override subsequent attributes.

Comment: This has fixed the issue with showing and hiding the album covers, however I'm still having issues with showing and hiding the .dropDownMenu div. It's what contains the options that the user has to select from. I've tried the following: 
$($("div.dropDownMenu").css("display", "none");      as well as
$("div.dropDownMenu").toggle();
And neither have worked. I've noticed in the chrome dev mode that the element style is being changed to display: block and then not changing back rather than the display property being changed in the CSS.

Comment: It looks like you may have an extra ending `</div>` tag.  Sometimes that can mess with the parsing.  Of course, it could also just be that you didn't copy/paste the preceding `<div>`. `$("div.dropDownMenu").toggle()` or `$("div.dropDownMenu").hide()` and `$("div.dropDownMenu").show()` should work from the code I can see.  One note, if there is only one menu, it would be better to reference it using its id like this: `$('#dropDownMenu')`.

Answer (score 0):

The marked answer solves the main problem, however in order to show/hide the dropDownMenu element after the user has made a selection the solution was to have a separate function that toggles the element when the element itself is clicked.
As opposed to having all 5 of the album sorting functions also hide the dropDownMenu.

```
$("div.dropDownMenu").click(function() {
    $("div.dropDownMenu").toggle();
});
```